# Can we assign values to function?

Tags: c++

Why the output is 30 here? And how fun()=30 is valid? What is meant by assigning function a value? And why removing static keyword throws segmentation fault?

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int &fun() 
{ 
    static int x = 10; 
    return x; 
} 
int main() 
{ 
    fun() = 30; 
    cout << fun(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: It's time to pick up a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or two, specifically the part where they demonstrate "references".

Comment: `fun()` returns a reference to the static variable `x` - and you are assigning to that. Not to a "function".

Comment: writing `int& fun()` is a tiny step towards avoid such misunderstanding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Let's walk through your program step by step:

1. inside `main()` `fun()` is called.
2. `fun()` has a static variable `x` (static means, that `x` is stored in a special part of memory and not on the stack, so its value is preserved between function calls) (It's like having a global variable that is only visible from inside `fun()`)
3. `fun()` returns a reference to `x` (references are almost like pointers)
4. You write to the returned *reference* of `x`, so `x` actually gets changed! (You *don't* write to the function)
5. now `x` is 30 and `fun()` returns 30 on the next call.

I hope this answers your first three questions.

## Why you get a segmentation fault without the static keyword:

In this case `x` does exist on the stack. So whenever you call `fun()` some memory gets allocated on the stack to hold `x`. When `fun()` returns, this memory will be deallocated.

Now, the reference returned by `fun()`, will reference a piece memory, that is not allocated by your program anymore. In other words, the returned reference will reference a memory address, that does "not belong to your program", thus you are not allowed to write to it. And so you get a segmentation fault.

## Can we assign values to function:

To answer the actual title of your question: Yes, we can, using function pointers:

```
int foo(int x) {
    return x + 1;
}

int bar(int x) {
    return x * 2;
}

void main() {
    int(*f)(int) = foo;
    // int   the function pointed to returns an int
    // (*f)  f is the name of the function pointer
    // (int) the function pointed to takes on int as paramter
    // = foo; f now points to the function foo()

    (*f)(3); // the same as foo(3), returns 4
    f = bar; // now f points to bar()
    (*f)(3); // the same as bar(3), returns 6
}
```

Comment: `.data` or `.bss` (where `static`s are stored) segemnts are not the same as heap.

Comment: No, you can't assign values to functions. You can assign values to function pointers, but not to functions in C++. Try assigning anything to `foo` in your example, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

`fun()` returns a reference to static variable `x`, to which you assign the value `30`. You don't assign anything to the function itself. In fact, it is not possible to assign anything to a function in C++.

Comment: Thanks!! And why keyword static is required here?

Comment: Because of the keyword `static` you can return a reference to that object from the function without causing undefined behavior